# Windows 8 - USB 3.0 Port works sometimes with superspeed sometimes with normal speed

Tags: windows-8, hard-drive, usb

With the same external hard disk, my USB 3.0 port sometimes transfers with superspeed, sometimes transfers with normal speed.

For instance, when I plug in my external drive, it is 2.0 but when I restart the computer it is superspeed again.

Sometimes it is vice/versa.

Is there any BIOS setting to cause this?

**Edit:**
I have an assembled desktop.
My device is a Toshiba Canvio 3.
All updates of Windows 8.1 are done.
The device works with superspeed everytime I connect it to my laptop or desktop in my office.

**Update:**
I have updated the BIOS. For now, there is no problem. I'll wait for tomorrow and than tell if this is a solution or not.

**Edit:**
The problem is still there. But one thing is solved. Everytime I restart computer after I plug my device in, it is superspeed.

Comment: Ensure first that all drivers are patched (usually found in Windows Update as optional updates). Please also specify the make of your computer and of the USB device.

Comment: Instead of restarting your computer, have you tried ejecting and plugging the drive back in?

Comment: @Jason yes, I tried it. It behaves the same as restarting. Except, once it is not spuerspeed, it stays that way no matter how much I plug out and in.

Comment: Have you checked for a BIOS or other firmware updates on your computer manufacturer's website? Edit: The computer is custom built. Have you checked for bios updates or other firmware updates from your motherboard vendor?

Comment: Also, are you trying to use your drive through a front panel port? How does the drive behave when connected to a port on the board?

Comment: @TorpedoBench I use the rear port, not the front panel port. [BiosAgentPlus](http://biosagentplus.com/result/e0189ed11b452d3490daa6a88a9ce692#) says that, I need to update some of my dirvers. Is there a freeware to do it?

Comment: @cagirici Since it's a whitebox, we would need the model of your motherboard.

Comment: It is MSI Z77A-G43. I'll do the update now.

Comment: Which make is the USB3 controller?

Comment: @harrymc where can I see this information? I don't see anything about USB ports in System Information

Comment: @harrymc Intel.  And since he's running Windows 8, he [shouldn't be installing any drivers](http://www.intel.com/support/chipsets/usb3/sb/CS-033977.htm).

Comment: @Jason: You might see that in the Device Manager under Universal Serial Bus controllers. But it won't help for Intel.

Comment: @cagirici, you can find BIOS updates for your board at MSI's website. That is the only solution I can think of here.

Comment: @TorpedoBench: Your advice seems to have worked, so better post it as an answer.

Answer (score 1):

The culprit is likely an outdated BIOS version on your motherboard. You can find BIOS revisions on [MSI's website](http://ca.msi.com/service/download/).